# How to extract value from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jmeter, javascript-security

I have below javascript response

```
<script language='javascript'>var p=parent;
p._isDuplicateDocName=false;
p.reloadDocStructureAfterSaveAs("xyz");
```

I am trying to extract 'reloadDocStructureAfterSaveAs' value from above using Regular expression extractor

Expression: `reloadDocStructureAfterSaveAs("(.+?)")`

but value is not getting extracted into reference variable. Please advice

Comment: Can't you do it programmatically?

Comment: If the value is not being extracted, what value, or error, are you getting back? Where is the regex code?

Comment: [Regex - Special Characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special)

Comment: What does `_isDuplicateDocName` do? What does .`reloadDocStructureAfterSaveAs("xyz");` do? Is `parent`, a...  Node?, Number?, Object,?

Comment: blaze_125: default value given in extractor is getting extracted, not getting any error

Comment: zer00ne: _isDuplicateDocName : response checks if document is duplicate, if yes then saves it with new value reloadDocStructureAfterSaveAs("xyz"). I need to pass 'xyz' to proceeding requests

Comment: I think we are not seeing enough code to get and understand the context of your question(s). See if you can refactor your question and/or sample to include as much as you can share with us. We don't want to know your secrets but, we must have enough to make the right assessments and suggestions and I fear we are missing too much to help you at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You must escape outer parenthesis with `\` as `(` & `)` has special meaning i.e., for grouping.

Use the regex as follows:

```
reloadDocStructureAfterSaveAs\("(.+?)"\)
```

Use Debug Sampler & View Results Tree in combination while debugging the script.

Comment: Thank you Naveen. expression reloadDocStructureAfterSaveAs\("(.+?)"\) and use of debug sampler helped me to solve my issue.

Comment: glad it worked for you. If answer is helped you can accept (click on tick mark next to the answer) and upvote (up arrow, next to the answer) it which is The best way to say thanks in SO. As you are a new comer, I am giving headsup :). Welcome to StackOverFlow.